# Sanctions for cheating at an exam

Tags: cheating

What is a standard penalty for an undergraduate student who is caught cheating at an exam (e.g. using a mobile phone to copy the material from the lecture notes)?

I am aware that this massively varies from one university to another, but I would still like to know if there are some general guidelines, for example "usually some form of suspension from the university for a period of time" or "if a repeated misconduct it's the permanent suspension".

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possibilities, including

- Zero for the exam but nothing further
- Failure of the course
- Expulsion from the university

The first would be something imposed by the professor. An appeal might be possible or not. The others would probably need to be imposed by a disciplinary board of faculty.

There might be some defenses possible in some cases, such as the rules not having been made clear or arguments about the severity of the offense.

Things have gotten a bit murky in the COVID era with online exams and poor communication about rules.

I've never actually heard of suspension for a period of time. I think the other three options are more likely. Expulsion would usually be final and might be reflected on any transcripts. Local privacy rules would apply, of course.

Comment: In the UK, the first and other penalties are not decided by the professor, but by the academic misconduct panel, including several academics.

Comment: About the last paragraph: when I was a student, about 35 years ago, a couple of students were suspended for six months/one year from taking any exam. But since I'm a faculty, I've never heard of anything similar. It's worth noting that at the time serious cheaters would also have their picture and generalities displayed along the corridors. Nowadays such punishments would be indeed impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your university probably has a stated policy for dealing with various forms of academic misconduct ( cheating, plagiarism, ...). That should describe both processes and penalties.

It's  best to follow the processes rather than making case by case decisions on your own.

Comment: Sorry , but I don't understand the purpose of your answer and I don't like the presumptions you are making here. Of course my university has stated policies and I am very aware of what these are. Why do you think I should not be interested in how these issues are arranged at other places and why do you assume I plan to use this information to break the policy at my university and make decisions on my own? I think it's really not fair to assume bad motives on my end without me writing a single word indicating such a possibility. Is it really not ok to make comparisons of different universities?